# How would I make my code reload instead of crashing after an error in python selenium chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have it as wait until clickable so I can keep reloading on my own but i want it to just do it on it's own because constantly reloading isn't fun and is a waste of time

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('link.com')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000)
AddToKart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/section/div[15]/div/div[2]/button'))).click()```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
count = 1
while(count==1):
    count=0
    try:
       wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/section/div[15]/div/div[2]/button'))).click()    

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        count=1
        try:
            driver.refresh()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Just wrapp it with while and try/except

Comment: Hey It didn't work for what I need to to do, the element is still present on the web page, I just need it to click whjen the element is clickable and if it isn't clickable I want it to refresh and continue doing that till it is clickable, I also don't want to open a new browser window every time, sorry If I missed something and am mistaken

Comment: Just change the where while loop start , what happen if element is not clicable and you click it any error is thrown ? just wrap the cick element step in the while loop , use the same logic as in code